# code for connecting windows phone emulator to pc

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i have a project this year wherein i need to connect windows phone to pc through a wifi connection and perform basic synchronization operation. . .
being new to this application development i have no idea where to start 
the problem i am facing is 
which protocol and service should i use .
i just want to know a basic code to establish connectivity between emulator and computer and transfer a simple message or something else...
i searched many sites but couldn't find a simple connectivity code.
i am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for windows phone

Comment: You could describe a bit more of your problem. You won't get code here unless you show what you have tried (post your code). So My answer conatains only ideas and a link to a sample.

Comment: my main problem is how do i establish a connection between pc and emulator,which is on same wifi network, is there any sample application .. .thanx for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But there are several ways to pull data from within an application to the phone:

- Webservices, you create a web service and your application calls the webservice ([sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/355937/How-to-use-webservice-in-Windows-Phone-7-applicati))
- Socket based (for example UDP)

If you want to do something without your app running (not being visible to the user) then you might have a look at background tasks. A sample is [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP7ScheduledTaskAgent-6450bcf1). Though you're limited in what can be done in a background task, refer to Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: i want to use socket based one  . . . .

Comment: i have worked on a similar project but in vb 2008 , also it was LAN based quiz using tcp\ip